How do I prove that the set of numbers whose dyadic expansions are not unique are countable?
I am aware that the set of numbers whose dyadic expansions are not unique are the multiples of the negative powers of 2. But how do I prove that is the only set whose dyadic expansions are not unique? I have been thinking about it for a while; I have even posted a similar question but for some reason, I can't fully understand it. I don't know if there is some prerequisite knowledge I don't have. Does anyone have an idea?
Edit: For context, dyadic expansions are binary expansions.

Presumably you mean real numbers.

It has to end in all $0$s or all $1$s to have a non-unique representation.

@ThomasAndrews Yes, I do
